# Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2, TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, python3, python-2.7

I have installed TensorFlow 2, Python 2 and Cuda 8.

I am not able to use any TensorFlow modules, it seems they are not compatible.

Anyone knows which version of Python and Cuda should I use with TensorFlow 2?

Comment: Did you mean (C)uda ? Also please show any error if any ?

Comment: I've just edited your question as it should be presented. Please take time to write properly and also always post error messages when relevant. Thank you and welcome.